# Unknown gap between list elements during transition

Tags: html, css, react-transition-group

I'm animating the height of li elements using react-transition-group and there is a pesky gap that forms between two elements before the middle elements transitions in. It can't be the margins What is causing this gap and how can I get rid of it? https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-sandbox-forked-m1t7l

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the `padding` on `.MuiListItem-root`.

Even empty `<li class="MuiListItem-root ...">`s currently have the following rules applied:

```css
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
```

Just get rid of those styles and the gap will disappear.

Comment: yep :) thought I tried zeroing that but clearly not